# How to remove specific lines in a table

Tags: html, web

This code I have written will generate lines in between every row and column. Can you please tell me how can I remove some lines in between columns while keeping others (as shown in the last image).

```
<form action="method="POST">
<table border="1" style="width:400px">
  <tr>
    <td>January:</td>
    <td>$20</td>
    <td>february:</td>
    <td>$30</td>
    <td>March:</td>
    <td>$60</td>   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>April:</td>
    <td>$20</td>
    <td>May:</td>
    <td>$30</td>
    <td>June:</td>
    <td>$60</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Description:</td>
    <td colspan="5"><input type="text" name="data" value="some data" size="44"/></td>    
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="updatebutton" value="Update" /></form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That's just how tables work.

Alternately you can remove the borders from the table, put a DIV in each cell and selectively style the borders of the DIVs.